# How to position checkbox to the right of the text?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

How do I achieve this?
There is no API for it.

```
<label formControlName="item" nz-checkbox>Item</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `flex-direction: row-reverse` on the nz-checkbox or add `class="ant-checkbox-rtl"` on it (not recommended).